# asterisk Command to check which DID was called (Asterisk)

Tags: asterisk

Need help, please assist me!

I need a command that would let us know which DID is the incoming call landed on.

Comment: 1) Welcome to StackOverflow. We deal with software development issues. Your question, however, has nothing to do with software development and thus is not fit for this site. 2) Your question also lacks details and does not show you did any research. When you ask this question on another site (for example, SuperUser or ServerFault) you need to state what you have tried and what you have trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

You can see CDR(if your dialplan not changed DST)

You can see verbose log:

```
  asterisk -r
  core set verbose 3
```

If that not help, you can enable sip debug

```
  asterisk -r
  sip set debug on
```